# Why can't I run snort as IPS even though IDS mode run fine?

Tags: windows-10, snort

I'm trying to run snort2 in IPS mode but getting this error

```
`ERROR: ./classification.config(0) Unable to open rules file "./classification.config": No such file or directory.'
```

checked snort.conf and the name file they are the same but it seem cmd can't find the file? What should I do?